# Gradle Composite Build with different project types (ant, maven)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, ant

Is it possible to create a Gradle Composite Build using maven or ant+ivy projects as subprojects?

If yes, how to do it?

I checked the documentation at [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) and it has some reference to ant and maven, but not so clear about this type of integration.

My goal is to have a composite build where the app is a gradle project and the libraries can be gradle, maven or ant and can be easily managed in a IDE like eclipse or IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `Gradle` to do the inter-projectType build orchestration. But you can transform the other projectType (`maven` or `ant`) into using `Gradle`, and then you can start to use composite gradle build between these modules. With that said, you probably have to maintain two build tools for the maven/ant module, if you still need them.

**NOTE** The composite build concept is essentially to help the cross-project development (intends to replace the binary dependency), it actually makes sense that you need to use `Gradle` across the board.

The documentation reference you mentioned are actually for the artifact publication flow (`maven-publish`, `ivy-publish`), that won't be useful in the build integration.